# ¿Cómo resolver este problema al listar entidades relacionadas?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jackson

tengo un CRUD, que funciona bien pero ahora tengo mis entidades relacionadas y ahi viene el problema, al no poder listarlas.
El problema esta en las listas asociadas, parece que no puede convertir a formato JSON.

DE ANTEMANO LES DOY LAS GRACIAS POR VUESTRA AYUDA

**MIS ENTIDADES SON:**

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity

@Table(name="presupuestos")

public class Presupuesto implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
     
    @Basic
    private String nombre;
    private long total;
    
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="presupuesto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Gasto> listaGastos;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    
    public Presupuesto() {
    }

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="gastos")

public class Gasto implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
      
    @Basic
    private String nombre;
    private String moneda;
    private Long   total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_presupuesto")
    private Presupuesto presupuesto;
    
    public Gasto() {
    }
```

**MI CONTROLLER DE GASTO**

```
@RestController
public class GastoController {
    
    @Autowired 
    public GastoService service;
    @Autowired
    public PresupuestoService presupuestoService;
    
    @GetMapping("/gastos/listar")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Gasto> obtenerGasto() {
     
       return service.obtenerGasto();
        }
       
    @PostMapping("presupuesto/{id}/gastos/crear")
    @ResponseBody
    public void crearGasto(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody Gasto gasto) {
       
        Presupuesto presu = presupuestoService.obtenerPresupuesto(id); 
        ArrayList <Gasto> listaGastos = new ArrayList();  
        Gasto nuevoGasto = new Gasto();
    //AGREGO EL OBJETO PRESUPUESTO EN LOS ATRIBUTOS DEL OBJETO GASTO
        nuevoGasto.setId(gasto.getId());
        nuevoGasto.setNombre(gasto.getNombre());
        nuevoGasto.setMoneda(gasto.getMoneda());
        nuevoGasto.setTotal(gasto.getTotal());
        nuevoGasto.setPresupuesto(presu);
        
        listaGastos.add(nuevoGasto);
     //GUARDO EL GASTO CON EL OBJETO PRESUPUESTO   
        service.crearGasto(nuevoGasto);      
        
        presu.setListaGastos(listaGastos);
     //EDITO EL OBJETO PRESUPUESTO Y GUARDO EN BD
        presupuestoService.modificarPresupuesto(presu);
      
    }
```

Al crear la lista de GASTO e insertar el objeto PRESUPUESTO, obtengo en mi BASE DE DATOS MYSQL todos los campos correctamente.
**Aqui el resultado en POSTMAN:**

```
{
        "id": 34,
        "nombre": "muesos",
        "moneda": "DOLAR",
        "total": 200,
        "presupuesto": {
            "id": 28,
            "nombre": "pasajes",
            "total": 1125,
            "usuario": {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "yaninaparenobeltran@gmail.com",
                "nombre_usuario": "Yanina Pareno",
                "password": "$2a$10$Eiim4YS7FapfXLMFtbVZi.0OtYA7tdBjkgSvbr058JAXKS9IklDz2",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "listadestinos": []
            }
        }
    },
```

***Cuando agrego @JsonIgnore, puedo listar todo bien. Sin él obtengo el siguiente error por consola:***

2022-11-15 11:22:12.336 ERROR 1784 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.back_prep_viajes.prepara.tu.viaje.model.Gasto["presupuesto"]...

Comment: el problema no es de hibernate, es de jackson, y se debe a que debes omitir en uno de tus dos objetos el otro relacionado

Comment: Hola gracias x tu respuesta, y perdón x mi ignorancia, pero a que te refieres con "omitir en uno de tus dos objetos" . Es decir que es lo que debería omitir?

Comment: una de las dos entidades, la referencia de uno simplemente no le pongas anotacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque las entidades son recursivas el padre hace referencia a los hijos y los hijos al padre, entonces cuando conviertes el Objeto a JSON con la librería Jackson crea un bucle infinito entre el padre y el hijo, por eso se debe ignorar la referencia del padre en los objetos hijos.

En tu código seria:

```
@Entity

@Table(name="presupuestos")

public class Presupuesto implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
     
    @Basic
    private String nombre;
    private long total;
    
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="presupuesto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Gasto> listaGastos;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    
    public Presupuesto() {
    }

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="gastos")

public class Gasto implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
      
    @Basic
    private String nombre;
    private String moneda;
    private Long   total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_presupuesto")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Presupuesto presupuesto;
    
    public Gasto() {
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfectamente al agregar @JsonIgnore en la referencia de la entidad padre.